# Error in value [[3L]] (cond): Object 'opcije' not found

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

This code down there is working just a way I want at the offline session.

```
opcije <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("language", "Zadatak 3 - No-", choices =  opcije), 
    textOutput("tekstZadatka"),
    tableOutput("tabela")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
output$tekstZadatka <- renderText({'some text whatever'})

    output$tabela <- renderTable({
        dataset <<- get(input$language)
        dataset
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

The variable opcije is globally defined char vector for getting one of n data frames from glob environment as well. However, after deploying this code to the server, I get that Object 'opcije' not found:

[image]

I will deeply appreciate any suggestions on how to overcome this.
Here is a log from the dashboard as well.
[image]

Comment: The global variable needs to be defined in the app.R file

Comment: I see. Added `opcije <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']`
Now my working directory does not exist even though is correctly given  

`An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

Fehler in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  E:\1. RAST I PRIRAST\0. Nastava\Prezentacije\Vezbe_prezentacije\Test does not exist
Ruft auf: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Ausführung angehalten`

Comment: Further debugging brings me to line with evaluation inside get.
Log says that I have an Error in get: invalid first argument.

Comment: The data.frame you're trying to reference has to be loaded in the App.R. Your environment is not published in shinyapps.io, only app.R and files that are loaded in the app.R and that are located in the app.R folder (or subfolder) are published

Comment: Here they are at the top of app.r, they were just comout. If I turn them, same happening. 
# for (n in 1:5){ 
# assign(paste("zadatak-", n, sep =''), read.csv(paste("E:/1. RAST I PRIRAST/0. Nastava/Prezentacije/Vezbe_prezentacije/Test", paste("zadatak-", n, ".csv", sep =''), sep ='/'))) 
# } 
It have to be sometnih with opcije variable, seems that typeof named list have to be given as argument 
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame'] do not return list, but char vec

Comment: In shinyapps, app.R directory is working directory. what is not in app.R directory (or sub) is not published

Comment: there are files in a directory, published, but feedback says that no such a file or dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The part I have been missing is that data have to be loaded within the server function, not inside app.R. Now after deployment, code works just fine.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
output$tekstZadatka <- renderText({'some text whatever'})

    for (n in 1:5){
        assign(paste("zadatak_", n, sep =''), read.csv(paste("Zadaci", paste("zadatak_", 
               n, ".csv", sep =''), sep ='/')))
    }
    
    output$tabela <- renderTable({
        dataset <- get(input$language)
        dataset
    })  
}
```